# How to build python3 package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've cloned some private python3 (can not share it).
I build it like this:

```
cd project
python3 setup.py install
```

I can use the project using:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/tool --help
```

This shows the right output.
But I want to use this like this:

```
python3 tool --help
```

Here I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.6: can't find '__main__' module in 'tool'
```

I see there is a `__main__` in the project. What is wrong?

Comment: from what you describe `tool` is a cli program. What you want to do is call the program with explicit call to python? or just not use the whole path? you should try `tool --help` directly as python's `/bin/` may already be in your `PATH`.

Comment: hm seems also not to work, it's a cli indeed. Python3 is in my /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: So what's `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/` exactly? Maybe this one should be in `PATH`, depends on what else is in there.